# Play framework file upload returns 403

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, file-upload, playframework

I have a simple method to upload a file in a service

```scala
def addFileTest(): Action[AnyContent] = Action { request: Request[AnyContent] =>
  val file = request.body.asMultipartFormData.get.file("file")
  val fileRef = FileRef(file.get.ref.path.toUri.toString)
  //FileRef is wrapper to File 
  Ok("File uploaded " + fileRef.getContentAsStringSync)
}
```

and a file with the following content:

```
<!-- saved from url=(0120)https://energyplus.net/weather-download/europe_wmo_region_6/NLD//NLD_Amsterdam.062400_IWEC/NLD_Amsterdam.062400_IWEC.epw -->
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></head><body>
LOCATION,Napier,Hawkes Bay,New Zealand,TMY2 NIWA 2980 D96484,933730,-39.46,176.86,12,3
```

When I try to upload a file on my local machine, everything works fine, I get this result back:

```
File uploaded <!-- saved from url=(0120)https://energyplus.net/weather-download/europe_wmo_region_6/NLD//NLD_Amsterdam.062400_IWEC/NLD_Amsterdam.062400_IWEC.epw -->
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></head><body>LOCATION,Napier,Hawkes Bay,New Zealand,TMY2 NIWA 2980 D96484,933730,-39.46,176.86,12,3
```

Deploying the service on AWS with an SSL certificate I get a 403:

```
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
```

Any ideas why I get a 403 on AWS? From my testing it looks like the HTML tag is at fault. I tried to remote debug it but it is not reaching my code.

Comment: 403 means you don't have permission to access the route. So, there is probably a problem with your AWS setup, maybe you need to configure API gateway... ?

Comment: @cbley uploading any other file except the ones that have <html> tags in them work on AWS.